# DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset bee_dataset not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load [the bees datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/bee_dataset) using the below code in google colab:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
(train_dt,test_dt), info_dt = tfds.load(name = 'bee_dataset',split=['train','test'],shuffle_files=True,as_supervised=True,with_info=True)
```

However, i face with the below error:

```
--> 129     raise DatasetNotFoundError(f'Dataset {name} not found.')
    130 
    131   builder_cls = _DATASET_REGISTRY[name]

DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset bee_dataset_150 not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first install `tfds-nightly`. *(Because this dataset new adding)*

```
pip install tfds-nightly
```

then you can run this code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = tfds.load('bee_dataset', as_supervised=True, split = 'train').batch(10)
image, _ = next(iter(dataset))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,5,figsize=(15,6))
for idx, axe in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    axe.axis('off')
    axe.imshow(image[idx])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]